# OpenGL dashed line

Tags: opengl, graphics, 2d, stipple

I'm trying to draw a 2d grid in opengl which contains dashed lines. I'm using `glEnble(GL_LINE_STIPPLE)` / `glLineStipple(...)` to do so. The problem is when I'm trying to drag the scene, dashes begin to move along the line and that is rather annoying, especialy if I'm drawing a circle or an arc - it looks like hypnosis! Does anyone know how to get out of this effect?

Comment: Line stipple is deprecated and removed from modern OpenGL anyway. Nowadays, one uses fragment shaders for that. the effect might also be achieved by textures.

Comment: Yes I know, but I have to deal with an old piece of code unfortunately

Comment: I believe if you use constant texture coordinates and an appropriate texture, you can more or less achieve the same effect without the undesired behavior when you move the line. All you need is a 1D checkerboard-like texture, and that sort of thing is supported even by implementations that don't use shaders. This is pure 2D right? Perspective projection can throw in another source of "hypnosis" if you try to do it the way I described, but that'll be a non-issue if everything has the same Z coordinate.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Please, can you give me an example how to do it?

Comment: @MikhailZimka: This is not done much since shaders were added around the same time line stippling became deprecated (though you might find a few examples in OpenGL ES 1.x). I found a really simple example for OpenGL [here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/archive/index.php/t-132759.html) (see Bob's answer).

Comment: @MikhailZimka: If you get it working, make sure to write an answer to your question. Other people may run into this problem in the future and the archived OpenGL thread post may no longer exist.

Comment: @MikhailZimka if you have no performance issues and want complete control of the style then look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18643561/2521214 just rewrite the `int` to `GLfloat` or whatever you use and instead od drawline use 2x `glVertex` ... inside `glBegin(GL_LINES); ...  glEnd();` do not forget to change the lengths and for step to your values ... (from pixels to world coordinate units)

Comment: @Spektre, thanks for your comment, but I have already found the solution using 1d texture.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, 1d texture method works for me fine, but is it correct to post an answer for my own question? As it was you who gave me an example, I'd like you to do it for me and I'll accept your answer.